# OOP and Class Composition error

Tags: c++, oop

So I have three classes, lets call a Car, an Engine, and a Stator Motor. Each one of them depends upon the other. So Car HAS AN engine, and an Engine HAS A Stator Motor.

Here is how I declare the classes in C++:

```
class Car {
private:
   bool Has_Windows;
   Engine _Eng_;
public:
   Car(bool Windows, Engine _Eng): Has_Windows(Windows), _Eng_(_Eng){}
};


Class Engine {
private:
   bool Racing_Car;
   Stator_Motor s_motor;
public:
   Engine(bool Car_Type_Engine, Stator_Motor _s_motor): Racing_Car(Car_Type_Engine),
          s_motor(_s_motor){
   }
};


Class Stator_Motor {
private:
   bool AC_220;
public:
   Stator_Motor(bool Voltage_Type): AC_220(Voltage_Type);
};
```

And in main, I initialize C as:

```
Car C(true, Engine(true, Stator_Motor(true)));
```

Now here is the problem, though when I am writing this down, the Intellisense in Visual Studio does find Stator_Motor constructor definition, but once I type it, it says it can't find no definition of Engine that has similar arguments. Why is this?

Comment: You need to define `Engine` before `Car`, Stator_Motor before Engine. and `Engine(bool Voltage_Type): AC_220(Voltage_Type);` is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you need to declare the symbols you are using before you are using them. And as you don't use pointers or references for the classes, you actually have to define them before using them.

So you have to define the classes in the opposite order:

```
class Stator_Motor { ... };

class Engine { ... };

class Car { ... }
```

Also, your constructor in `Stator_Motor` is wrongly named.

Comment: I think the emphasis here should be on *using* instead of *before*. A forward declaration can also appear *before* anything else. ;)

Comment: @joachim, thanks. But what if I have defined each class in a different header file, then how does one proceed?

Comment: @user1343318 Include the header files? Normally I would recommend against including header files in other header files, or avoid it as far as possible. But in this case there's really no way of going around it. So the header file which defines the `Engine` class has to include the header file which defines the `Stator_Motor` class, and the header file which defines the `Car` class must include the header that defines the `Engine` class. And the source that uses the `Car` class only needs to include the header file that defines the `Car` class, not the others (as they are already included).

Comment: Default constructor missing here in your case, in class car you have coded Engine _Eng_; and default constructor is called which is missing same is the case in Engine class calling default constructor of starter_motor. so provide defaults to both classes or call the parametrized ones. Generally in composition you have to provide default constructors